# Can't generate jni on Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I followed [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/eclipse_CDT_JNI_MinGW_64bit.php) tutorial and I got stuck at the "make all" step.

I got the following error:

```
javah -classpath ../bin HelloJNI
gcc -m64 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o libHello.so HelloJNI.o
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--add-stdcall-alias'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libHello.so] Error 1
```

makefile looks like this:

```
    # Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libHello.so

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
libHello.so : HelloJNI.o
    gcc -m64 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
HelloJNI.o : HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h
    gcc -m64 -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
HelloJNI.h : HelloJNI.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm HelloJNI.h HelloJNI.o libHello.so
```

I tried just removing --add-stdcall-alias, and got:

```
gcc -m64 -Wl, -shared -o libHello.so HelloJNI.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: HelloJNI.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
HelloJNI.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libHello.so] Error 1
```

I tried adding -fPIC, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this from the terminal:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/jni -fPIC -o libRecognizer.so -shared -Wl,-rpath, -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" facerec.cpp -lopencv_java249
```

so what this says is that I needed to link the library libopencv_java249.so and I was able to do that through  **-L/usr/lib/jni**  and **-lopencv_java249**

"/usr/lib/jni" is the path to the library.